# Знать наизусть

Tags: этимология

Здравствуйте!
Внезапно задумалась над словом "наизусть". Понятно, что "на-" - приставка, а что такое "изусть"? Если от "из уст", то зачем тут мягкий знак?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

НАИЗУСТЬ - исконное слово, образовано от "изусть" - на память, мягкий знак - это редуцированный гласный Ь, обозначающий падежную форму.

Интересно, что в др-рус. языке с 11 века существовали слова "рот и уста". Оба слова сложные в этимологическом отношении, но возможно, что рот - от слова рыть, а уста - от слова губа (о.-с. usta - уста, рот,  и.-е. корень us - губа).

Comment: Стало быть, рот - это "рыло"? 
А нога - "копыто", (ноготь, соответственно, "копытце"), глаз - "стекляшка". 
Ужас! Куда мы катимся?!
А вот приличные люди (наши предки) называли означенные части тела уста, пех и око соответственно.

Answer (score 0):

У меня два предположения: 
 1. Мягкий знак - это замещение звука и. Т.е. раньше звучало "из усти".
 2. В основе находится слово устье. Устье - место, из которого что-то изливается. Так что слова (речь) изливаются из устья, а слушатель запоминает произнесенное на слух, без предварительной записи. Т.о. Наизусть, это - запоминание прямой речи. И мягкий знак на своем месте.